# Adding row to table doesn't copy the formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel worksheet with multiple tables.

When I add rows to some tables, formulas are also copied to newly created rows. However, on some tables formulas aren't copied to the newly created row.

I want formulas to always be copied to a newly created row.

Do you maybe have any suggestions why tables might be acting differently? What could I check and how in order to find why tables act differently?

Comment: Something I've wondered about myself, kind of in the reverse category, sometimes I add a new row and the formula gets copied when I don't want it. This even happens when I delete all rows and then add a new row! The nearest I came up with is if the formula exist for all rows then it will copy, but if one of the cells in the column has a different formula (or a data) then it won't copy.

Comment: @gns100 Thank you for your comment. As it turns out this saved my day! Thanks! You might also post an answer and I will accept it.